# default-initialized Property of a GenericEntity

Tags: hiconic

If I have a `Property` of a `GenericEntity`, regardless if it describes a simple type (e.g. int) or a nullable type (like any Object), how to I get a default-initialized instance?

I mean `Property::getDefaultValue()` returns `null` for nullable types but also `Property::getType()::getDefaultValue()` does the same.

In particular I want for a `String` the default-initialized instance to be `""`, etc.

Or do I have to "manually" code this for all possible Object types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others eventually stumbling over this: This is not supported as I was hoping for. You have to use manual initialization based on java.

So along this lines:

```
                    try {
                        defaultValue = type.getJavaType().getConstructor(null).newInstance(null);
                        if (defaultValue == null) {
                            // this must not happen. error.
                            System.err.println("nulling did not work in getter!");
                        }

                    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```